# CakePHP: "password" and "password_repeat" can be empty on update

Tags: validation, cakephp, passwords, cakephp-2.3, change-password

my situation is this: I have two fields for the password of the user, "password" and "password_repeat".

On create (adding an user), both fields must be filled out obviously.
Instead, on update (editing an user), the fields can be left empty (so the user's password can remain the same). But if the "password" field is filled, then the "password_repeat" field must be filled.

For now I solved in this way and it seems to work:

```
public $validate = array(
        'password' => array(
            'minLengthOnCreate' => array(
                'allowEmpty'    => FALSE,
                'message'       => 'Must be at least %d characters',
                'on'            => 'create',
                'rule'          => array('minLength', 8)
            ),
            'minLengthOnUpdate' => array(
                'allowEmpty'    => TRUE,
                'message'       => 'Must be at least %d characters',
                'on'            => 'update',
                'rule'          => array('minLength', 8)
            )
        ),
        'password_repeat' => array(
            'passwordsMatchOnCreate' => array(
                'allowEmpty'    => FALSE,
                'message'       => 'Passwords don\'t match',
                'on'            => 'create',
                'rule'          => 'passwordsMatch'
            ),
            'passwordsMatchOnUpdate' => array(
                'allowEmpty'    => TRUE,
                'message'       => 'Passwords don\'t match',
                'on'            => 'update',
                'rule'          => 'passwordsMatch'
            )
        )
    );
```

In this way, the two fields are required on "create", but not on "update".
And now I do not like this, because I think there is a way to do it better.

But this is not enough: on "update", if the "password" field is filled in, the "password_repeat" field can be left blank. 
So I added this:

```
public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
        if(!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password']) && isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password_repeat']))        
            $this->validator()->getField('password_repeat')->getRule('passwordsMatchOnUpdate')->allowEmpty = FALSE;

        return TRUE;
    }
```

And also I like very little. 
But it seems that everything works well.

Suggestions?

Comment: If it works, why not. For a different approach using a behavior, read [working-with-passwords-in-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/). It will allow the same thing simply by using `"require" => false` as option - useful for above for edit forms.

Comment: @mark, because so many things can work, but it is good that things are functioning well and are done well :-)  
Thanks you!

Comment: you could always add something in your passwordsMatch function (I assume this is a custom function you made?) that returns true if the password field was filled but the password_repeat field was blank